# Upper bound this family of matrices in induced $2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, matrix-analysis

Let $\mathcal E = \{A \in \mathcal M(n \times n; \mathbb C): \|A\|_2 \le M \text{ and } \rho(A) < 1\}$ where $M \ge 1$ is some fixed constant and $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the induced $2$-norm. Is it possible to give an upper bound $C$ in terms of $M$ such that $\|(I-A)^{-1}\|_2 \le C$ for all $A \in \mathcal E$?

As commented by Omnomnomnom, it is not possible to find an upper bound of $\mathcal E$. What if now we modify the family to be
\begin{align*}
\mathcal F = \{A \in \mathcal M(n \times n; \mathbb C): \|A\|_2 \le M \text{ and } \rho(A) \le r\}
\end{align*}
where $M \ge 1$, $0 < r < 1$ are fixed constants and $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the induced $2$-norm. In this way $\mathcal F$ would be a compact set. Since $\text{Inv}$ is continuous, $\|(I - \cdot)^{-1}\|_2$ must achieve maximum on $\mathcal F$. Can we characterize the upper bound in terms of $r, M$?

p.s. I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2827844/is-it-possible-to-upper-bound-this-family-of-matrices-in-operator-norm/2827870?noredirect=1#comment5830802_2827870) but formulated in a way wasn't intended and it was answered.

Comment: The sequence of matrices
$$
A_k = \frac{k-1}{k} I
$$
precludes the existence of such a bound since each $A_k \in \mathcal E$, but $\|(I - A_k)^{-1}\| \to \infty$.  I would suggest that you reformulate the question as I advise below my answer on the other post

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: So the set is not compact as you commented in the other question?

Comment: The nice thing about compactness is that it guarantees the existence of the upper bound you're looking for (comactness is sufficient but not necessary).  Yes, the set you have described is not compact, and so we do not have this guarantee.  More specifically, my comment above proves that no upper bound can exist.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Thanks. What if we make the set to be compact by considering $\rho(A) \le r$ for some fixed $r < 1$?

Comment: As I say on the other question, then we necessarily have an upper bound.  I am not quite sure what that upper bound looks like in terms of $M$ and $r$, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer.

Up to a change of orthonormal basis, we may assume that $A$ is triangular.

If $A$ is normal (then diagonal), then it is easy to see that the required upper bound is $\dfrac{1}{1-r}$.

Yet, we can do much better. Assume that $M$ is large (for example $M\approx 100$) and choose $A=rI_n+MJ$ where $J$ is the nilpotent Jordan block of dimension $n$.

Then $\rho(A)=r,||A||_2\approx M$; moreover $(I-A)^{-1}=\dfrac{1}{1-r}I+\cdots +\dfrac{M^{n-1}}{(1-r)^{n}}J^{n-1}$ and $||(I-A)^{-1}||_2\approx \dfrac{M^{n-1}}{(1-r)^{n}}$.

Thus, if $r=0.9,M=100$ and $n=7$, the upper bound is larger than $10^{19}$.